# django parameter gets none even on redirect with parameter

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, django-urls

I have the following view that I want to only stay in the current view if it hasn't been redirected.

```
def surveys_view(request, survey=None):
    if survey != 'survey1':
            return redirect('matching:surveys', survey='survey1')
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^surveys', views.surveys_view, name='surveys'),
url(r'^surveys/(?P<survey>survey1|survey2)', views.surveys_view, name='surveys'),
```

The problem is that the survey variable is `None` every time causing infinite redirects.  I would think that after the redirect, the `survey` value would be set to '`survey1`'.

How can I have the survey parameter set to '`survey1`' instead of `None`?

Comment: post your urls.py file

Comment: @sideffect I added my urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in django `urls` list is parsed from 0th position, so in your urls,

```
url(r'^surveys', views.surveys_view, name='surveys')
```

has first priority, since the regular expression matches like any uri starting with `surveys<whatever>`, so either change the url settings to,

```
url(r'^surveys/$', views.surveys_view, name='survey-list'),
url(r'^surveys/(?P<survey>survey1|survey2)', views.surveys_view, name='survey-details'),
```

or change the order

```
url(r'^surveys/(?P<survey>survey1|survey2)', views.surveys_view, name='survey-detail'),
url(r'^surveys', views.surveys_view, name='survey-list'),
```

NOTE: notice there is also change in name parameter, since it is better to be set as a unique value

Comment: Wow, you know your stuff! Thanks @sideeffect